# How to gradually increase the philips hue light using android apis

Tags: android, philips-hue

From my code I try to schedule an alarm on philips hue and want the light brightness to gradually turn on from 0 to max value.

I use following code:

```
PHBridge selectedBridge = PHHueSDK.getInstance().getSelectedBridge();
        PHSchedule schedule = new PHSchedule("My Alarm");
        PHLightState lightState = new PHLightState();
        lightState.setOn(true);
        lightState.setTransitionTime(120000);
        lightState.setIncrementBri(1);
        schedule.setLightState(lightState);
        schedule.setLightIdentifier(lightIdentifier);
```

but the apis lightState.setTransitionTime(120000) and lightState.setIncrementBri(1) dient't seem to help. can someone help me with this.

Comment: Where are the docs for that API?

Comment: I could not find the doc. While codeing, I saw this as one of the api of PHLightState

Comment: What is not clear about the question that someone has voted to close it. I can try to be more clear though its already clear. Someone is just trying to act smart!!

Comment: Maybe explain what you expected to happen and what actually happened.  Include any error messages or stack traces.

Comment: If Philips isn't publishing javadoc, someone should clue them in to the fact that no docs == no product.

Answer (score 2):

transition time is uint16, so a max of 65535 is allowed.

see [Lights API](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/lights-api) - which is the best documentation you get at the moment... sigh.

I don't know whether it solves you problem, but one less bug.